# Why oVirt 4.1 RedHat contain a type "maximum memory" and reserved this on Host, blocking create another machines

Tags: kvm, ovirt

Why Virtual Machine on oVirt 4.1 RedHat contain "memory, and maximum memory". By default all maximum memory it is 2x memory, and this eat my memory space on Host. This blocking to create another Virtual Machine. In the oVirt 3.5 this "Max memory" don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This corresponds to new feature of [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsMemoryAllocation), it's maximum memory which could be hot-plugged:

> **maxMemory**
>
> The run time maximum memory allocation of the guest. The initial memory specified by either the  element or the NUMA cell size configuration can be increased by hot-plugging of memory to the limit specified by this element. The unit attribute behaves the same as for . The slots attribute specifies the number of slots available for adding memory to the guest. The bounds are hypervisor specific. Note that due to alignment of the memory chunks added via memory hotplug the full size allocation specified by this element may be impossible to achieve. Since 1.2.14 supported by the QEMU driver.